# Regex help to match expression and exclude certain match

Tags: regex

I am trying to solve this problem where the same phrase is present in one or more lines but I only want to match the correct form.

In my case I want all case IDs in a line block

my line block looks like this

```
!# Reason: Reason in Detail
!# ACL: Rule
!# Modifier: Mod1 - 11/17/05 - ccc REMEDIATION: added expiration date
!# Modifier: Mod2 - 06/21/06 - qqq REMEDIATION: changed expiration date
!# Modifier: Mod3 - 4/22/2008 - renewed for 1 yr per REQ<TEST1XX>
!# Requester: Req1
!# Group: imp1
!# Exp. Date: 4/22/2009
!# Reference Case : http://case/C1TEST1TEST1XXX
!# Case : C1TEST1TEST1TEST2
!# Case # C1TEST1TEST1TEST1X
```

I am using the Regular expression `\bCase :.*\b\W` to match all the cases but some line blocks contain a reference case which I want to avoid. Not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

My Regex fiddle: `https://regex101.com/r/HA3zEe/1/`

Comment: Would checking for the !# starting point work for your purposes. If you don't want to include it either use groups or a positive lookbehind. So for example: `(?<=!# )Case :.*\b\W`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use grouped values from your regex you can use a regex like this:

```
Reference Case\s*:\s*\S+|Case\s*:\s*(\S+)
```

[**`[Regex Demo]`**](https://regex101.com/r/DknffM/5)

I use `Reference Case\s*:\s*\S+` to match what you don't need then don't let its value in group, so in else situation regex check for `Case\s*:\s*(\S+)` that I grouped its value by `(\S+)` - Check `Group 1` -.